# get parameter value in url Django

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, get

I am new to Django, I want to receive a value from the URL and then use it in a filter, but I am having this problem.

where value is a field of a model, in the view.py

```
class ModelNumber(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer 

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model.objects.all()
        value = self.request.query_params.get('value')
        return Model.objects.filter(value = value)
```

at urls.py

```
path('model_number/(?P<receipt_ballot>\w+)$', views.ModelNumber.as_view()),
```

and Model.py

```
class Model(models.Model):                                                              
    value = models.CharField("Number Value", max_length=12, null=True)
```

in the url

http://192.168.0.3:8080/model_number/001-000002/

the error :

Page not found (404)

The current path, /model_number/001-000002/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Hi Tony, Welcome to SO! can you elaborate your question further as I am finding it difficult to understand the exact issue you are facing

Comment: @Bernard'BetaBerlin'Parah 
I already edited it, at the time of sending the parameter in the url I get an error Page not found (404)

Comment: you need to edit your url to show the value you want to get `http://192.168.0.3:8080/?model_number=001-000002/`. then you can get the value in with your current code

Comment: another way is to use kwargs  like this ...`self.kwargs['param_name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kwargs` key defined in url to get the value of that key. Like:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        # What you wanted
        value_of_url_parameter = self.kwargs.get('receipt_ballot')

        queryset = Model.objects.all()
        value = self.request.query_params.get('value')
        return Model.objects.filter(value = value)
```

Comment: seriously you should stick to one answer instead of waiting for people to post comments and answers and you keep making edits. If you're not sure chill. it's not a contest

Comment: Haha!!! You think yourself a influencer!!! Thats good for you...

Comment: Cheer it out bro, Let me explain what happend... Firstly, I thought it as function based views.py so, i answered it. By, the time I editted you did a comment. So, it seems to you like I am copying you. Yes, I agree I would have pointed that out.. Thats my mistake... Have a great day mate!!!

Comment: so I was right to make the assumption, I think you should leave the answer though, I already asked OP to accept yours. I am good mate. Please put back the complete answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify your url to capture the parameter

`http://192.168.0.3:8080?model_number=001-000002/`

```
class ModelNumber(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer 

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model.objects.all()
        value = self.request.query_params.get('value')
        return Model.objects.filter(value = value)
```

notice the question mark in the url

Comment: You could not use ```/001-000002/``` after query parameter

Comment: so why not point that out instead of outrightly copying it and adding it to your answer?

Comment: I am not angry..Peace mate

Comment: Also, I think ```value = self.request.query_params.get('value')``` it should be ```self.request.query_params.get('receipt_ballot')``` in this case

Comment: yes that's correct, I ignored the receipt_ballot to give a more generic answer, reason why I used value